# mongoid creating document with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have two mongoid models:

bid.rb and supplier.rb

```
class Bid
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :amount, type: BigDecimal
  embeds_one :supplier
end
```

I would like to query the embedded `:supplier` `:name` and display the `:bid` `:amount` in a JSON response.

I have tried this all kinds of ways, the furthest I got was:
`Bid.all.pluck(:supplier, :amount)`  which only returns the supplier id and amount.

Right now I can write `bid_data = Bid.all` to get the following JSON response:

```
{"bid_data":
[{"_id":{"$oid":"58a0a9a531d77f01529a22ba"},
    "amount":"5335.0",
    "supplier":{"_id":{"$oid":"58a087b131d77f01529a229c"},"name":"Ford","comment":3}
    }]}
```

How can I query the `Bid.supplier.name` in a controller?

Ideally I would like something like `Bid.all.pluck(:supplier.name, :amount)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say:

```
embeds_one :supplier
```

you're really saying that the `bids` collection has a `Hash` field called `supplier` and that `Hash` should be wrapped up in the usual `Mongoid::Document` stuff. That means that you can query `supplier` like any other `Hash`:

```
Bid.where('supplier.name' => 'Ford')
```

Comment: But how do I write a query to display the `:amount` and  `:supplier.name` together?

Comment: Are you trying to query on the name or pull just the name out?

Comment: Trying to query the :supplier.name and the corresponding :amount from the bids

Comment: But `Bid.where('supplier.name' => 'Ford')` queries the supplier name and gives you `Bid`s so I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: But .where just filters the Bid. I need to display both the bid amount and the supplier name in a table. So, maybe something like ['Ford', 5335]

Comment: So what is stopping you from doing that? Given `bids = Bid.where(...)`, what's wrong with `bids.each { |b| puts b.supplier.name, b.amount }` and similar things?

Comment: Ahh: `Bid.pluck('supplier.name', :amount)` will work I was trying to use :supplier.name